# iphone PDF view CGPDFDocument

Tags: iphone, pagination, scroll, zooming, cgpdfdocument

I am developing an app where I need to show PDF documents. After many hours of googling I was able to build up a view to show the PDF document fetched from a URL.

I know only to display a single page. using `CGPDFDocumentGetPage(ref, pageNumber)`.

What I would like to have.

1. Pagination function.
2. Zoom
3. Scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the UIWebView instead of reinventing the wheel?

Comment: UIWebView according to me is not an elegant solution. It will be the last one i will be choosing. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: What functionality do you need that web view doesn't provide? The only thing that can think about is to load/view separate pages.

Comment: other functionality UIWebView can't handle: Hyperlinks, editing the pdf, thumbnails, and CGPDF should be a more efficient (and faster load wise) solution.  I am working on the poster's problem as we speak also and found this post and thought i'd add some insight into why people need CGPDF.